# JSON Feed Timestamp

Tags: json, timestamp, fullcalendar, unix-timestamp

I am using FullCalendar JS Plugin for a tool I am building and I am creating a JSON Feed.

```
        "id": "'.$row['AppointmentID'].'",
        "title": "'.$row['AppointmentName'].'",
        "url": "'.$row['URL'].'",
        "class": "event-important",
        "start": "1364407286400"
    },
```

The time stamp for the start of this is 1364407286400 I for the life of me cannot work out how this timestamp is formated. I thought it was Unix but I generated a timestamp for today and replaced it and it is still not showing.

Can anyone point me in right direction?

Comment: This timestamp is in milliseconds.

Comment: Are *you* setting the value of `start`, or is something else? And what "is still not showing"? If I do this in Javascript: `new Date(1364407286400);` I get "2013-03-27T18:01:26.400Z"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a timestamp in miliseconds. You can easily test this value using:

```
$test = (int)(1364407286400/1000);
var_dump((new DateTime())->setTimestamp($test));
```

the output will be:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2013-03-27 11:01:26.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
      string(10) "US/Pacific"
}
```